# Is there a tool for the conversion of duplicate literals into final Strings/magic numbers in Java?

Tags: eclipse, constants, final, repeat, magic-numbers

I have some Java files that use the same String values up to 20 times each, and I want a tool that replaces those Strings with a `private static final String STRING_TO_CAPS_AS_CONSTANT` or something along those lines. If it can also convert numbers into magic numbers, that would be great. I'm using Eclipse but if it's a standalone tool I can still make use of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Eclipse provides that already. If you select the whole String and press CTRL+1 it should give you the opportunity to choose: "Extract to constant". This will implicitly replace all occurrencies of your String with the new constant.

Comment: Ah, so it's the same as Refactor / Extract Constant..., never noticed that before.

Comment: I found out by accident too ;-)